# PL/SQL Function Error

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have an error at this function.
I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPNAM(empno in number) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  DECLARE nam VARCHAR2(40);

BEGIN

  SELECT BEZEICHNUNG 
    INTO nam 
    FROM PROJ_PROJEKT 
   WHERE PROJEKTID = empno;

 RETURN nam;

END EMPNAM;
```

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Error at line 7: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
    continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
    merge pipe purge

5. select BEZEICHNUNG into nam from PROJ_PROJEKT where PROJEKTID=empno;
6. return nam;
7. END EMPNAM;
```

Comment: BTW, it's better to write `nam PROJ_PROJEKT.BEZEICHNUNG%type;` then `nam varchar2(40);` - this way, your function won't break when someone enters a project with a longer name (possibly after altering the column length in the table)

Comment: You can name you variable as lastname instead of nam if, when you use it in a SQL statement, you namespace it with the function name: eg. "select lastname into emp_lastnam.lastnam ..."

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you need the `DECLARE` keyword there. The [syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm) is:

```
create or replace function foo
 return return-type
is
 (vars)
begin
 (code)
end foo;
```

Comment: Actually, `IS|AS` is used in procedures as well. In anonymous blocks however, you can use `DECLARE`. :)

Comment: you don't need the declare option in a procedure. you could use it, you don't have to. Anonymous blocks need them when declaring variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `DECLARE` keyword

For example:

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION patient_func 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
  patient_name VARCHAR(20); 
BEGIN 
  SELECT first_name 
  INTO patient_name
  FROM patient_tbl 
  WHERE patientID = 123;

  RETURN patient_name;
END patient_func;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare must not be used in your code and

```
SELECT BEZEICHNUNG 
    INTO nam 
    FROM PROJ_PROJEKT 
   WHERE PROJEKTID = empno;
```

In above statement what is "BEZEICHNUNG"... if it is a name it can't directly moved to nam
the column name can be moved into the identifier... the above code must be like as follows

```
select lastname into nam
from proj_projekt 
where projektid=empno;
```

here "lastname" is the column name which is moved into identifier "name"